# Visual Studio 2010 Filters?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, filter

[image: Basically what I'm talking about.]

I'm trying to compile the Face Recognition/Detection code that I had found on the internet. However, the filters are preventing certain classes to be seen. Is there an easy way i can fix this? I've never filtered out classes before (i.e. cognition, gui etc) so not sure how to link them or make them visible to eachother. If someone can PLEASE help me out with this i would really appreciate it! It's been driving me crazy...

Comment: Hard to guess what you are talking about.  Don't add .h files to your project, only .cpp files.  The .h files get #included.  Tell the compiler where they are located in the settings.

Comment: That's not possible.

http://code.google.com/p/visual-control/downloads/list

If you look at the source code in there, you'll realise what i mean.... The code is split into separate filters, however they can't been seen by other files, even if the include is specified. That's my problem